# How to scale date based event systems, such as Google Calendar dealing with million of events at any given time

Tags: date, calendar, google-calendar-api, eventtrigger

I'm searching for architecture or algorithm by which an efficient schema can be used to trigger events based on time. Meaning for ex. that when "Sun, 06 May 2012 23:54:11 +0300" arrives n events should be fired imminently. (where N can be between 0 and N).

The question is not about scaling the delivered system (be it message queue, or http get or what ever...) but about efficient detection of the events that should be triggered at the given time. Or to be event more percise, I guess that I'm asking about the proper data structure to allow efficient O(n) ? polling for n number of events based on date window.

References would be of great value,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Heap lets you keep a collection of items, with the following actions at cost O(log n):
 -- Insert arbitrary item
 -- Pop minimal item
And if I'm not mistaken, you can peek at the minimal item at O(1).

So, I think you should keep your events in a Heap (with the order specified by time), and:
-- whenever the heap changes, schedule action for the time of the minimal (=next in time) item
-- for complex events, make the event insert itself again, with the time of next invocation

This isn't strictly based on a date window, but I think it may be even better for you.